# TortoiseSVN update from Codeplex ends with "File or directory is corrupted and unreadable"

Tags: windows-7, tortoise-svn

I am in the process of working on [Umbraco](http://umbraco.codeplex.com/)  and when I go throuogh the process of downloading it from Codeplex via TortoiseSVN, I get the following error message.

```
    C:\Projects\Umbraco\branches\rb403\umbraco\umbraco.webservices\Properties
Can't move 
'C:\Projects\Umbraco\branches\rb403\umbraco\umbraco.webservices\Properties\.svn\tmp\entries' 
to 
'C:\Projects\Umbraco\branches\rb403\umbraco\umbraco.webservices\Properties\.svn\entries': 
The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
```

Has anyone seen this before and or know of a workaround? to download everything and sync?

Answer (score 0):

Run a cleanup on your working copy, then start the update again until it succeeds.

This is actually a bug in Win7, which will be fixed in the upcoming SP1.
See [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprogeneral/thread/df935a52-a0a9-4f67-ac82-bc39e0585148) for details about the problem.